# How to avoid ambiguous match for two different elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest for avoid the Ambiguous template match for both '**mfrac**' and '**msub**' elements. Here scripts are coded to remove the 'Space1' text nodes which are present at

- first or second child of msub or mfrac with first text node
- first or second child of msub or mfrac with last most text node

***Note***: Able to get the required result but getting recoverable error message.

**XML:** (comments are given for explaining the requirement, not for real)

```
<article>
    <disp-formula id="eqn1">
        <math>
            <mfrac>
                <mrow>
                    <msub>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi mathcolor1="blue">Space1</mi><!--Remove: FRAC's First Child's very first text node (even thou it is under MSUB, but with respect to MFRAC should not have SPACE as  -->
                                <mi>H</mi>
                            <mi mathcolor1="blue">Space1</mi><!--Remove: SUB's First Child's last text node -->
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi mathcolor1="blue">Space1</mi><!--Remove: SUB's Second Child's very first text node -->
                                <mn>2</mn>
                            <mi mathcolor1="blue">Space1</mi><!--Remove: SUB's Second Child's last text node -->
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                </mrow>
                <mfenced>
                    <mi mathcolor1="blue">Space1</mi><!--Remove: FRAC's Second Child's very first text node -->
                       <mrow><mi>2</mi></mrow>
                    <mi mathcolor1="blue">Space1</mi><!--Remove: FRAC's Second Child's last text node -->
                </mfenced>
            </mfrac>
        </math>
    </disp-formula>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="msub/*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]//mi[@mathcolor1][contains(.,'Space1')]"><!--SUB space at end and before of SUBSCRIPT text -->
        <xsl:variable name="varPreceded1"><xsl:value-of select="preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!='']
            [1][generate-id(ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]/parent::msub)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]/parent::msub)]"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="varFollowed1"><xsl:value-of select="following::text()[normalize-space(.)!='']
            [1][generate-id(ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]/parent::msub)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1]/parent::msub)]"/></xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when  test="string-length($varFollowed1) eq 0"><remove2/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when  test="string-length($varPreceded1) eq 0"><remove1/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mfrac/*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=0]//mi[@mathcolor1][contains(.,'Space1')]"><!--FRAC space at begin end of NUMERATOR text -->
        <xsl:variable name="varPreceded1"><xsl:value-of select="preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!='']
            [1][generate-id(ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=0]/parent::mfrac)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=0]/parent::mfrac)]"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="varFollowed1"><xsl:value-of select="following::text()[normalize-space(.)!='']
            [1][generate-id(ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=0]/parent::mfrac)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=0]/parent::mfrac)]"/></xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when  test="string-length($varFollowed1) eq 0"><remove2/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when  test="string-length($varPreceded1) eq 0"><remove1/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Error message:**

```
Recoverable error
  XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for
  /article/disp-formula[1]/math[1]/mfrac[1]/mrow[1]/msub[1]/mrow[1]/mi[3]
```

Comment: Your XSLT code is incredibly hard to understand. Perhaps you could show the output (the actual and expected output are the same, if I understood correctly) and explain the rules? (Actually, you should know by now that outputs should always be included in an XSLT question...)

Comment: @MathiasMüller, here Space1 is removed, if it is found at first text node as well as last text node within MFRAC or MSUB (usually having two children), of course required text are available only thing, the error message while running the scripts.

Comment: H#<subscript>#2<subscript>, here '#' is nothing but 'SPACE' required to be removed. 'H' is first child of MSUB, having space at the end of first child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you get that warning (from Saxon?), it tells you exactly which two templates where matched and it takes the last one when transforming the sample. If that gives you the correct result and you don't want that warning, you can set an explicit `priority="5"` on the `xsl:template` for instance, `5` being an example number greater than the possible computed priorities http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict. Or you have to change your match pattern to make sure not both match that `mi` element, whether that is possible and makes sense depends on your requirements which I have not fully understood.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the suggestions, I have tried with priority attribute, unable get the required result but avoid the ERROR message, because first SPACE1 to be removed, because it is first TEXT node for MFRAC too. NOT ANCESTOR also not giving the required result, because 1st and 2nd  SPACE1 should be removed from MFRAC rule, 3rd and 4th are by MSUB rules. Given sample XML is common math text where FRACTIONs can have these SUB, SUP related text. See the updated input XML text with comments.

Answer (score 4):

Only you can tell under what circumstances each of the two rules should fire. My guess from your sample is that if something has an msub ancestor then you don't care about the fact that it also has an mfrag ancestor. If that's the case then your first rule takes priority, and the simplest solution is to give it higher priority using an explicit "priority" attribute. The alternative would be to change the patterns to be mutually exclusive, which might mean adding a predicate `[not(ancestor::msub)]` to the second rule - but I would go for explicit priorities.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the suggestions, I have tried with priority attribute, unable get the required result but avoid the ERROR message, because first SPACE1 to be removed, because it is first TEXT node for MFRAC too. NOT ANCESTOR also not giving the required result, because 1st and 2nd  SPACE1 should be removed from MFRAC rule, 3rd and 4th are by MSUB rules. Given sample XML is common math text where FRACTIONs can have these SUB, SUP related text. See the modified Input XML text with comments.

Comment: You've packed too many questions in that comment to be comprehensible; in any case, a thread quickly becomes incoherent if you modify the original question in response to a posted answer. It's better to post a new question, complete in itself.

Comment: what is the priority syntax?  <xsl:template match="foo"> would change to something like this <xsl:template priority=5 match="foo">

Comment: Syntax example is helpful: <xsl:template match="foo"> would become <xsl:template priority="4.9" match="foo">